# Prolem with fixed position and linear gradients with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, linear-gradients

I need a fixed div that have a linear-gradient background. In all browser the background is always in the right place inside the div, instead with Google Chrome (23.0.1271.52 beta-m) the div content stay fixed but the background scrolls along the page.

Look at this with Firefox then with Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/h3WNk/

I tried using `background-attachment: fixed` but this way gradients are not displayed at all.

Seems that using absolute positioning works but I need that div fixed on bottom left corner of the page even when user scroll the page.

Comment: It looks the same for me in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: It looks the same in Safari, Chrome and Firefox here too!

Comment: I am using Chrome 23.0.1271.52 beta-m and you?

Comment: I run into this issue only on mobile browsers, and only sometimes. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also tried Chrome 22 (non beta) same result.
Surprisingly I found out that adding an `opacity` attribute makes webkit render correctly the background without scrolling it with the page!
What a bug